# Fourier transform , of a function computation

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

I need help with this Fourier transform computation.

$$F(w)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x|+ix}e^{-iwx} \, dx$$

Need help to compute.

Comment: **Hint**. Split the Integral into $\int_{-\infty}^0 + \int_0^{\infty}$ and then use properties of $|x|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 steps: (1): $$\text{F.T.} [e^{-\alpha |x|} ] = \dfrac {2\cdot\alpha }{\alpha ^2 + k ^2}  $$

(2) We denote $F.T.[f(x)]=F(k) $. Consider the identity: $$F.T.[f(x) \cdot e^{-iqx} ] = F(k- q) $$

Now, if you prove these 2 - the answer should be obvious.
write incase you need more assistance.

Edit:Calculation No.1: $$\int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|x|}e^{-ikx}=\int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-|x|}\cdot \cos(kx)-e^{-|x|}\sin (kx)=2\int \limits_{0}^\infty e^{-|x|}\cdot \dfrac{e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx}}{2}=$$ $$=\int \limits_{0}^\infty e^{ix(k-1)} - \int \limits_{0}^\infty e^{ix(-k-1)} = \dfrac{1}{i-ik} - \dfrac {1}{ik+i}=\dfrac{2}{k^2+1} $$
Calculation No.2: $$\int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{iqx}e^{-ikx}= \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-ik(x-q)} = F(x-q) $$
And finally: $$F.T.[e^{-|x|}\cdot e^{ix}] = \dfrac{2}{(k-1)^2+1}$$

Comment: I still don't understand .... Thank you for the help

Comment: @marussT I edited